# Looking for title of 1990s movie from memories of scenes

Tags: story-identification, movie

This little puzzle has been bothering me for about fifteen years now. A while back I re-watched a bunch of sci fi films from the 1990s, but one was missing that I had some clear and rather embarassing memories of.

What I remember:

There are a bunch of scenes on either a spaceship or grounded station. Possibly on a desert world or blasted terrain. There's a hero and his male antagonist (both caucasian, dark haired), plus the hero is accompanied by a pretty brunette for most of the movie. It's a typical polished 1990s sci fi B movie, but could have been made anywhere between 1988-1996. I'm thinking more mid-1990s. Direct to TV or VHS, the sort of thing on at 2am on the sci-fi channel in the mid-nineties.

The key scenes:

At some point, the brunette is taking a shower and the bad guy ambushes her with some sort of hypnotic, swift-blinking light that apparently either knocks her out or puts her into a trance.

Later, the bad guy is sitting/standing over an examination table, where he's apparently brainwashing the still-nude woman. He calls the hero and says "you wouldn't believe the view". He's some kind of jock/colonial marine type, plus evil.

At some point the hero rescues the woman, but it turns out she's now a sleeper agent for the bad guy(s) and sabotages the mission (whatever that is). I'm not clear on this last part, but I *think* it turns out her brainwashing is irreversible and so the woman either sacrifices herself or leaves the crew.

Amazingly, I haven't been able to find any record of "young attractive brunette in a sci fi film is nude in a shower and then gets her brain fried by some guy with a laser pointer", despite it being a pretty specific moment.

I've checked through a few movies like Space Marines, Phoenix and Terminal Voyage, but come up with nothing. Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Was it a Hollywood type movie? Had you/have you ever seen any of the main actors before or since (even if you don't recall their names)?

Comment: It was a Hollywood movie - something along the same lines as Mindwarp or the second body snatchers remake, typical polished but cheap sci fi 1990s stock. I don't have any memories of the actress except her being a brunette, similar to Terry Farrell (Dax from Star Trek Deep Space 9). Hero's name was one syllable, but no idea what it was. I may e completely wrong but it might have been a sort of Universal Soldier setup where there's one good and one bad marine type, fighting over something.

Comment: Apparently the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/202596/80s-sci-fi-movie-man-walking-from-a-desert-gets-to-a-road-and-stops-an-aerodyn

Answer (score 10):

Found it. Looks like my childhood memory of the movie was a little warped and inaccurate in places, but the general idea was right.

The movie is **[Solar Crisis](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0100649/)** (1990), and the scene I vaguely recalled is just over the 30 mins mark.

I can't believe I've finally identified this after all this time :)

**Warning : Contains mild nudity**

Comment: You can accept your own comment as the answer. This will cause it to be flagged as "answered", so it won't show up on the list of unanswered questions.