# 80s sci-fi movie, man walking from a desert, gets to a road and stops an aerodynamic autonomous semi

Tags: story-identification, movie, post-apocalyptic, artificial-intelligence

I remember watching a (maybe post-apocalyptic) sci-fi as a child, which featured an autonomous semi truck looking very similar to the one that Tesla motors presented. This part of the movie took place in surroundings similar to those of *Mad Max*, in that it was a desert like place.

A guy walked onto a road, stepped in front of this running autonomous cargo semi and the semi truck stopped and explained it was done based on a protocol programmed to save lives or something along those lines. The truck told the main character to step aside to allow the truck to continue. Then the main character somehow managed to hitchhike it, and got to a city I think, the rest I don't remember.

Comment: When did you watch it? In what country were you and what country was the movie set? Is there anything else you can remember from the movie?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 18):

Could this be [Solar Crisis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_Crisis_(film))? There's a scene where one of the characters stands in front of a self-driving truck. It stops and he (and his companion) climb on.

Comment: I think this is it. Funny how many details fall out of memory after more than 20 years :)) I now see I overglorified this movie a bit in my head :D 

Well, its time to watch some B grade sci-fi now :))
Thank you !

Comment: @Áčko If this is the answer you were seeking, please click the green check next to the answer. Thanks!

Comment: That was my thought, too.