# '90s film where someone stand in front of massive high speed train

Tags: story-identification, movie

Looking for a name of a film I saw long ago. Feels like late 90s ish.

All I remember ... these people need to get to a fortress complex far across a desert. There are these massive automated uber high speed black vehicles that go there, a train maybe. On a hunch and unknown risk, some one stands in front of one coming. It stops dead in front of him and they are able to hop on and stow away in.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is science fiction or fantasy about this film?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Automated high-speed train-like vehicles were scifi in the 1990's

Comment: Almost certainly a dupe of this; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/202596/20774

Comment: Yes! Been to that thread... Solar Crisis is it. Cheers!

Comment: @FuzzyBoots  sorry, didn't explain how this is set in dystopian future with robot vehicles and space stuff.

Comment: @SonOfJ: Since the other question doesn't have a confirmed answer, I added one here. You can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed by the querent that this is [*Solar Crisis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_Crisis_(film)), where there is a scene where one of the characters stands in front of a self-driving truck to make it stop so he and his companion can climb on.

[image: Movie Poster for *Solar Crisis*]

> To stop a solar flare from destroying the Earth, Steve Kelso is tasked to drop an artificially intelligent bomb on the Sun from the spaceship Helios. Arnold Teague, who believes the danger to be overstated, attempts to sabotage the mission so he can profit from the panic. Teague's agents on Earth clash with Kelso's father, Admiral "Skeet" Kelso, and his son, Mike.

### The scene in question